# C60 Macro Ojects

Tags: electromagnetism, gravity, material-science, chemical-compounds

What would happen if you could make a ball or hollowed geometric shaped say the size of a basketball made out of C60.. due to its superconductivity could it have exotic or anti- effects on gravity and magnetism?

Answer (score 2):

In its superconducting phase, it'll have exactly the same effect on magnetic fields as any other superconducting object like the [Meissner-effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meissner_effect).

It won't affect gravity other than by its mass - because electricity and gravity are separate things.

Comment: No idea why you got upvoted and I down. If it affects mass, then since gravity is defined by mass that is like saying its effects (not affects) gravity. Wish  I had a more thorough and comprehensive answer to my original question instead of profile score gaming which I care nothing about unlike most on here apparently.

Comment: I never said it affects mass - I only said that gravity is only affected via its mass and since a C60 molecule has mass, your hollow object has mass. There is no other effect known. I told you that your object looks like a regular superconductor. Hence, it behaves like a one. You can look up the properties of superconductors everywhere on the internet - I even provided you with a link. I don't know what else to say...